# MVC form posts automatically after reading Smart Card

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smartcard

I have an `MVC` application and there is a `Create` view with `CardNo` field in it. I want to read the card numbers by a `Smart Card Reader` and click the `CardNo` field and then read the smart card. The card number comes to the field but after reading the form posts automatically. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the smart card reader is triggering an enter.  You could stop the submit, and then submit it on your own terms;

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // stops the submit

     // or do something else to determine if you're ready to submit
}
```

Comment: It is ok but in this case the form cannot be submitted when pressing Submit button. How to tweak this?